# Losing reference to 'this' when invoking Reflect.get

Tags: javascript, this

I have the following method to map a command to a function inside an object:

```
const mapHandler = (str, obj) => {
  if (!Reflect.has(obj, str)) {
    return null;
  }

  const candidateHandler = Reflect.get(obj, str, obj);
  if (typeof candidateHandler !== "function") {
    return null;
  }

  return candidateHandler;
};
```

I have a simple class holding some commands I want to invoke using the handler:

```
class MyClass {
  obj;

  constructor() {
    this.obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
  }

  create() {
    return this.obj.a;
  }

  remove() {
    return this.obj.b;
  }
}
```

I set things up and run:

```
const myobj = new MyClass();
const handler = mapHandler("create", myobj);

console.log("Found", handler);

const res = handler();
```

But I get this:

```
Found [Function: create]
/workspaces/sandbox/index.js:22
    return this.obj.a;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'obj')
    at create (/workspaces/sandbox/index.js:22:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspaces/sandbox/index.js:35:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I am clearly losing the reference to `this` inside `myobj` and most likely due to `Reflect.get`. How can I fix this and make sure the handler mapper does not cause the returned function to lose its reference to `this`?

Comment: No, this is not related to `Reflect.get`. It's simply the call `handler()` that passes no `this` value. Use `handler.call(myobj)`, or `return candidateHandler.bind(obj)` from `mapHandler`.

Comment: Really not clear why you're using `Reflect` at all here. `const candidateHandler = obj[str]` is much simpler and does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes I know that `Reflect` is an overkill, but I was experimenting with some other stuff. In this question i wanted to understand how much `Reflect` is a culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference a function it's not bound to any `this`.

You either should use `Function::call()` to make a bound call, or `Function::bind()` before the call to invoke to function on a proper `this`.

Note when using `Function::bind()` you cannot rebind it later (`Function::call()` with a different `this` doesn't work either), since `Function::bind()` makes something like:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(ctx, ...args){
  const self = this;
  return function(...extraArgs){
    return self.call(ctx, ...args, ...extraArgs);
  }
}
```

```js
class MyClass {
  obj;

  constructor() {
    this.obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
  }

  create() {
    return this.obj.a;
  }

  remove() {
    return this.obj.b;
  }
}

const mapHandler = (str, obj) => {
  if (!Reflect.has(obj, str)) {
    return null;
  }

  const candidateHandler = Reflect.get(obj, str, obj);
  if (typeof candidateHandler !== "function") {
    return null;
  }
  // here we bind the func to allow calling without a context
  return candidateHandler.bind(obj);
};


const myobj = new MyClass();
const handler = mapHandler("create", myobj);

console.log("Found", handler);

const res = handler();
```